# Как увеличить шрифт кода в IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Скачал Intellij IDEA но на экране шрифт кода мелкий, подскажите как увеличить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Font
там есть Size